# Akka cluster bootstrap in Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, akka, akka-cluster

I'm trying to deploy a cluster with the following configuration:

```
 server1.address                          server2.address                                                                                        
+----------------------------+           +----------------------------+                                                                          
|  docker-compose            |           |  docker-compose            |                                                                          
| +------------------------+ |           | +------------------------+ |                                                                          
| |+----------------------+| |           | |+----------------------+| |                                                                          
| || Akka                 -------2551-------- Akka                 || |                                                                          
| ||                      -------9100--------                      || |                                                                          
| ||                      -------8100    | ||                      || |                                                                          
| |+----------------------+| |    |      | |+----------------------+| |                                                                          
| |+----------------------+| |    |      | |+----------------------+| |                                                                          
| || Service              ------------------- Service              || |                                                                          
| ||                      || |           | ||                      || |                                                                          
| |+----------------------+| |           | |+----------------------+| |                                                                          
| +------------------------+ |           | +------------------------+ |                                                                          
+----------------------------+           +----------------------------+
```

I use Akka Cluster Bootstrap to initialize the cluster and `akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.contact-point-discovery.discovery-method = config` to define cluster nodes.

```
akka.remote.artery {
  canonical.hostname = ${?CURRENT_HOST}
  canonical.port = 2551
  bind.hostname = 0.0.0.0
  bind.port = 2551
}
akka.management.http {
  hostname = ${?CURRENT_HOST}
  port = 9100
  bind-hostname = 0.0.0.0
  bind-port = 9100
}
```

The problem is that Akka container cannot initialize cluster (using Cluster Bootstrap) because it cannot connect to itself using canonical (external) hostname. In general I cannot connect to host ports from within container.

The only solution I've found so far is to allow traffic from my docker compose network using [`sudo iptables -I INPUT 3 -i <compose-network> -j ACCEPT`](https://forums.docker.com/t/cannot-access-network-port-on-host-using-bridge-network/14631). Is it really a way to go?

Comment: could you show your `docker-compose.yaml` file and the full error returned by akka? As you can see in [docker networking](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/), you have the network, the host port and the container port. You can access from contiainer A to B (both in the same network) using `<protocol>://<service-name>:<CONTAINER_PORT>`. If you want to send requests form the outside (I think this is your case), you have to use `<protocol>://<docker-ip>:<HOST_PORT>`. If it is possible, share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @GastónSchabas I'll try to make an example later ...But I'm starting to think that I need to use Docker Swarm so all my containers are in the same docker network and don't use server's real address